# Swtich case in strings

Tags: c++

I have an error while I compile my code.

Error Output:

```
main.cpp: 35:16: error: switch quantity not an integer
```

I dont know why. The code is as follows:

```
int Values(string letter) {
    switch( tolower(letter) ) {
        case 'a' : a.setTotal();
        break;
```

Regards

Comment: Is this `tolower` your own function? What does it return?

Comment: What exactly is it you don't understand in the error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `string` is not a `char`, it's an object representing an array of chars.
Instead of passing in a `string` to that function, you should pass in a `char`.

[`tolower(int)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/tolower/) exists in C++ and it was meant to take characters, not strings.

---

Here's another way to fix this that needs less changes to your code:

Since I'm pretty sure that `letter` is going to be a `string` of length `1` judging by the name, you can change your `switch` statement to access `letter[0]`, which will be the first character in the `string`. You would also have to pass `letter[0]` to `tolower`.

Answer (score 2):

`letter` is string, so `tolower(letter)` produce a string. But your case is character ('a'). Additionally it is impossible in C/C++ to use switch for string.
user this line instead:

```
switch( tolower(letter.data[0]) )
```

Comment: I think index operation ( [] ) is not overloaded for std::string? But not sure;)

Answer (score 0):

The switch inscrutvion takes only enumerated types(enum), chars(char) or integers (int, unsigned, long)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to work with a single character.

Change your function's parameter:

```
int Values(string letter)
```

to this:

```
int Values(char letter)
```

And the `switch` statement will work.